# generate Image from R,G,B pixel in C++

Tags: opencv

I have a follow code:

```
   double R = (double)(img->imageData + img->widthStep*i)[j*3];
   double G = (double)(img->imageData + img->widthStep*i)[j*3+1];
   double B = (double)(img->imageData + img->widthStep*i)[j*3+2];
```

and then i put some condition for R, G, B.
Now I want to generate new image from new pixel value R, G, B  in C++.

Highly appreciate for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should take a look at that:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
using namespace cv;

int main(int ac, char **av){

  cv::Mat src = cv::Mat(Size(1920, 1080), CV_8UC3, Scalar(0, 0, 0));
  std::vector<cv::Mat> rgbChannels;
  cv::cvtColor(src.clone(), src, CV_BGR2RGB);

  cv::split(src, rgbChannels);

  cv::Mat r = rgbChannels.at(0);
  cv::Mat g = rgbChannels.at(1);
  cv::Mat b = rgbChannels.at(2);
  unsigned char max1, max2, min1, min2, R=0,G=0,B=0;
  for (unsigned int y =0; y < r.rows; y++){
      for (unsigned int x =0; x < r.cols; x++){
          max1= (R>G)? R:G;
          max2 = (max1>B)? max1:B;
          min1= (R<G)? R:G;
          min2 = (min1<B)? min1:B;
          if( R>95 && G>40 && B> 20 && (max2-min2)>15 && (R-G)>15 && R>G && R>B) {
              r.at<uchar>(y, x)=R;
              g.at<uchar>(y, x)=G;
              b.at<uchar>(y, x)=B;
          }
      }
  }

  rgbChannels.clear();
  rgbChannels.push_back(r);
  rgbChannels.push_back(g);
  rgbChannels.push_back(b);
  cv::Mat RGBoutput;
  cv::merge(rgbChannels, RGBoutput);
  cv::imwrite("output.png", RGBoutput);
  return 0;
}
```

By the way if you want make operation on colors you should take a look at the HSV color space for more precise results.

Comment: Hi. Thank you so much for your answer. But in this case, i want to show image from camera, after that i change some values (R,G,B) and set that pixels to the current image that receive from camera. How can I do that?

Comment: Use a VideoCapture a modify your frame with the piece of code I gived to you, and do a cv::imshow of the modifyied frame.
(take a look here for the video capture: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html )

Comment: hii. I want to detect skin region from your codea/s: r = rgbChannels.at(0);
  g = rgbChannels.at(1);
  b = rgbChannels.at(2);
  unsigned char max1, max2, min1, min2, R =0,G=0,B=0;
  for (unsigned int y =0; y < r.rows; y++){
       for (unsigned int x =0; x < r.cols; x++){     
             max1= (R>G)? R:G;
     max2 = (max1>B)? max1:B;
     min1= (R<G)? R:G;
     min2 = (min1<B)? min1:B;
  if( R>95 && G>40 && B> 20 && (max2-min2)>15 && (R-G)>15 && R>G && R>B){
     r.at<uchar>(y, x)=R;
     g.at<uchar>(y, x)=G;
     b.at<uchar>(y, x)=B;
  }
But after merge, Image  don't change anything.

Comment: I am looking at your pb. give me few minutes

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot that Opencv uses BGR by default. I edit my piece of code.

Comment: Take a look at my piece of code I edited it this should be solved

Comment: so ? is everything ok ? don't forget to valid the answer please.

Comment: Hi unsigned char max1, max2, min1, min2, R=0,G=0,B=0;
  for (unsigned int y =0; y < r.rows; y++){
       for (unsigned int x =0; x < r.cols; x++){     
        max1= (R>G)? R:G;
     max2 = (max1>B)? max1:B;
     min1= (R<G)? R:G;
     min2 = (min1<B)? min1:B;
      
   
  if( R>95 && G>40 && B> 20 && (max2-min2)>15 && (R-G)>15 && R>G && R>B)
  {
     r.at<uchar>(y, x)=R;
     g.at<uchar>(y, x)=G;
     b.at<uchar>(y, x)=B;
I change as your guide but the result is not change. I have more question like i want to define initialize value of R,G,B from 0 to 255. How can I do? Tks you for your help.

Comment: you can use cv::Scalar (take a look at opencv's doc.) I am surprised because I run your test and it is fine for me...

Comment: Hi, can you show for me your code with my test? Kindly Regards.

Comment: Becasue when i use your code, i add new variable: unsigned char R, G,B but when i debug they need initialize. How can i initial them (0,0,0)?

Comment: cv::Mat src = cv::Mat(Size(1920, 1080), CV_8UC3, Scalar(0, 0, 0));

Comment: Now it works but i don't know when i change condition of R,G,B (if Loop) but new image doesn't change anything